# Can python compress logical operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this line of code:

```
if x + dx < 0 or y + dy < 0 or x + dx == len(grid) or y + dy == len(grid):
```

However that feels clunky and overly long since I'm doing the same comparison on multiple expressions. On a larger comparison this could end up taking up a ton of unnecessary space.

Is there any way to compress it into something like:

```
if x + dx or y + dy < 0 or x + dx or y + dy == len(grid):
```

Comment: Since your concern is "that [it] feels clunky and overly long", you can wrap the _long and clunky_ code within a function, and just call it when needed. Something like: `def calc(x, dx, t, dy, grid): if ((x + dx < 0) or (y + dy < 0) or (x + dx == len(grid)) or (y + dy == len(grid))): pass`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, boolean operators can't be compressed; computer languages are rather bad at understanding English grammar.

Just compute the `x + dx` and `y + dy` results *once* and use the results in your test:

```
xdx, ydy = x + dx, y + dy
if xdx < 0 or ydy < 0 or xdx == len(grid) or ydy == len(grid):
```

Alternatively, if you inverted the tests, you can make use of *chained comparisons*:

```
if not (0 >= x + dx > len(grid) and 0 >= y + dy > len(grid)):
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

What you are looking for is better made by defining functions that will make it look better, for example:

```
def is_negative(x):
    return x < 0

def is_grid_length(x):
    return  x == len(grid)


if is_negative(x + dx) or is_negative(y + dy) or is_grid_length(x + dx) or is_grid_length(y + dy):
```

Comment: This is only more verbose; why not make a `bounds_check()` test that tests *both conditions* for a given `v, dv` pair?